# How to read file through ssh/scp directly

Tags: linux, redhat

I have a program written in C/C++ that reads two files and then generate some reports. The typical workflow is as follows:

```
1> scp user@server01:/temp/file1.txt ~/ then input my password for the prompty

2> my_program file1.txt localfile.txt
```

Is there a way that I can let my program directly handle the remote file without explicitly copying the file to local first? I have tried the following command but it doesn't work for me.

```
> my_program <(ssh user@server01:/temp/file1.txt) localfile.txt
```

Answer (score 15):

You need to use `ssh user@host "cat /temp/file.txt"`.

You can use this to redirect it to stdin of your program: `ssh user@host "cat /temp/file.txt" | my_program` or you can actually call this in your program with an fork/exec. Or like you described it to generate a temporary file: `my_program <(ssh user@host "cat /temp/file.txt")`

Other options would be to use sshfs with fuse or using a ssh (or VFS) library in your program.

Comment: I tried this solution and it doesn't work. my_program only reads the localfile.txt but the remote file.

Comment: Your program needs to read from stdin for my example. Some do that automatically if you specify no input file, some do it if you specify '-' as filename.If your program does not do that, then you need to use the temp file function you suggested in your question, i adjust the answer. The main paint of my answer is using "cat".

Comment: also you will probably need to setup passwordless ssh using authorized keys else you are going to have you program send your pssword

Answer (score 6):

If you are really on Red Hat Linux, this should work:

```
ssh user@host cat /temp/file1.txt | my_program /dev/stdin localfile.txt
```

Using a single `-` instead of `/dev/stdin` may work as well, but it would depend on whether `my_program` was written to interpret an argument of `-` as "read this file from stdin".

Also, this might not work if `my_program` expects to be able to seek around in the first file (I/O streams are generally non-seekable), but if all it does is read from the first byte to the last byte, it should be OK.